# rotation matrix along z axis python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to rotate a vector along a z axis:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np

theta = np.radians(90)
c, s = np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)
R = np.matrix([[c, -s, 0], [s, c,0], [0,0,1]])
v = np.matrix( [ 0.        ,  1.83124623, -0.52249415] )

print R*v.reshape(3,1)
```

I am getting in return:

```
[[ -1.83124623e+00]
 [  1.12131492e-16]
 [ -5.22494150e-01]]
```

Comment: This code is working fine. What is the problem?

Comment: The result is wrong. I should get in return: [[ 1.83124623e+00],[  1.12131492e-16],  [ -5.22494150e-01]]

Comment: The result is right: if you ignore the third axis, which is invariant anyway, you may think of the operation as  taking something along the positive y-axis and moving it counter-clockwise by 90 degrees, which gives you something along the negative x-axis: look at what your transformation is doing to the standard basis for R^3.

Comment: The standard convention is that angles run *counterclockwise*.

Comment: I have to make sure. If I want to run clockwise, I should change my angle from 90 to -90, right?

Comment: Negative angles go clockwise for a [right-handed coordinate system](https://www.evl.uic.edu/ralph/508S98/coordinates.html), yes.